# How to deny all when the host is a development server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to set a "deny from all" only when the host of the website contains

```
.*\.dev\.site\.com$
```

When the url contains it i want to allow only ip adresses that are listed

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 63.162.42.59
allow from 95.56.43.101
```

When i move the website from the dev environment to a production server i don't want the deny all. I hope this check can be done automaticly

Comment: You could use [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) to set up a flag when the request HOST header is part of your dev domain and make that part of your `DENY` configuration (for example, see [ALLOW](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) directive description); be aware however that this does not “secure” your development environment from outside access.

Comment: and how can i “secure” the development environment from outside access? that is my main goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dev\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^63\.162\.42\.59$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^95\.5\6.43\.101$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```